# trying to use econnect in crm as a plugin but could not load assembly

Tags: plugins, workflow, crm, econnect

So we have recently decided to go with econnect to communicate from crm to gp and we are trying to implement econnect in crm as a plugin. the issue is when calling that plugin it fails and i get the error [image: error message]
im not really sure how to get crm to see the Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect dll. I tried registering it to the gac and disc (as well as db) but the plugin registration tool wouldn't let me. any help would be much appreciated

error depicted in image is: "Error occurred in Execute Method: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Gp.eConnect, Version 12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Please edit your question, take out the image, and put the text of the error into the question directly. Screenreaders can't read the text in the image, it's not searchable, and it's barely readable it's so tiny.

Comment: Also, to figure out what the actual error is, have a look at [Fuslogvw](http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/viewing-assembly-binding-logs-using-fuslogvw-exe/) in the Windows SDK. It allows you to log the details of .net assembly binding errors and it can tell you where it's looking for the dll or if it's a dependency of the dll that's actually missing.

Comment: Are you referencing a specific plug-in you wrote (referencing eConnect?) or a eConnect plug-in itself that causes this error?

Comment: Shane_Yo im referencing the eConnect dll itself, and Nanhydrin i will try using Fuslogvw and let you know my results

Comment: @Nanhydrin i used fuslogvw on my local machine only showed the nuget.exe and didn't show any with the CRM on premise application

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2010/11/09/how-to-reference-assemblies-from-plug-ins.aspx